# Java PMD, Writing a custom rule set

Tags: java, pmd, rule

I have a problem regarding the api of java abstract rule. Take for instance this particular piece of code which was obtained from this website, https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.3.6/customizing/howtowritearule.html

```
package net.sourceforge.pmd.rules;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleContext;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.rule.AbstractJavaRule;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTExpression;

public class CountRule extends AbstractJavaRule {

       private static final String COUNT = "count";

       @Override
       public void start(RuleContext ctx) {
               ctx.setAttribute(COUNT, new AtomicLong());
               super.start(ctx);
       }

       @Override
       public Object visit(ASTExpression node, Object data) {
               // How many Expression nodes are there in all files parsed!  I must know!
               RuleContext ctx = (RuleContext)data;
               AtomicLong total = (AtomicLong)ctx.getAttribute(COUNT);
               total.incrementAndGet();
               return super.visit(node, data);
       }

       @Override
       public void end(RuleContext ctx) {
               AtomicLong total = (AtomicLong)ctx.getAttribute(COUNT);
               addViolation(ctx, null, new Object[] { total });
               ctx.removeAttribute(COUNT);
               super.end(ctx);
       }
}
```

When i ran this rule, i cant seem to run the start or the end methods, instead the rule jumped to the visit method and starts visiting all the expression nodes within the abstract syntax tree. Does anyone know why it does not call the start and end methods?

Comment: Cross-post: https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188192/thread/fb461eb0/#64ab